# Sorting LowToHigh PHP/XML/Javascript

Tags: php, xml

This is quite frustrating have been working on it all day. 
I am trying to sort The XML document with price from Lowest to highest. 

Using PHP.

The XML data is only using the City London, Just for reference

and i did not wish to place the Price in descending order on the XML due to the information i wish to manipulate will not be added statically.

First the codes

```
var xHRObject = false;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    xHRObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
else if (window.ActiveXObject)
    xHRObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

function retrieveInformation() 
{
    var city = document.getElementById("selectCity").value;
    var type = "";
    var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i=0; i < input.length; i++)
    { 
        if (input.item(i).checked == true)
            type = input.item(i).value;
    }
      xHRObject.open("GET", "retrieveHotelInfo.php?id=" + Number(new Date) +"&city=" + city + "&type=" + type, true);
      xHRObject.onreadystatechange = function() {
           if (xHRObject.readyState == 4 && xHRObject.status == 200)
               document.getElementById('information').innerHTML = xHRObject.responseText;
      }
      xHRObject.send(); 
}
```

-

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="retrieveHotelInfo.js"></script> 
</head> 
<body>
Destination:
<br /> 
<select id="selectCity" onchange="retrieveInformation()">
    <option value="London" selected="true">London</option>
    <option value="Paris">Paris</option>
    <option value="New York">New York</option>
    <option value="Chicago">Chicago</option>
    <option value="Seattle">Seattle</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />
Price Range:
<br />
Budget<input name="range" value="Budget" type="radio"  onclick="retrieveInformation()"/>
Standard<input name="range" value="Standard" type="radio" onclick="retrieveInformation()" checked="true"/>
Luxury<input  name="range" value="Luxury" type="radio"  onclick="retrieveInformation()"/>
<div id="information">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

-

```
<?php
 $xmlFile = "hotel.xml";
 $HTML = "";
 $count = 0;
 $dt = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile);
 $dom = DOMDocument::load($xmlFile);
 $hotel = $dom->getElementsByTagName("hotel"); 

 foreach($hotel as $node) 
 { 
 $city = $node->getElementsByTagName("City");
 $city = $city->item(0)->nodeValue;

 $type = $node->getElementsByTagName("Type");
 $type = $type->item(0)->nodeValue;

 $name = $node->getElementsByTagName("Name");
 $name = $name->item(0)->nodeValue;

 $price = $node->getElementsByTagName("Price");
 $price = $price->item(0)->nodeValue;

if (($type == $_GET["type"]) && ($city == $_GET["city"]) )
{
    $HTML = $HTML."<br><span>Hotel: ".$name."</span><br><span>Price: ".$price."</span><br>";
    $count++;
  }
  } 
  if ($count ==0)
 {
  $HTML ="<br><span>No hotels available</span>";
 }

 echo $HTML;   
 ?>
```

if needed the xml document is written just like this

```
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <hotels>
    <hotel>
        <City>London</City>
        <Name>The Rilton</Name>
        <Type>Luxury</Type>
        <Price>300</Price>
    </hotel>
    <hotel>
        <City>London</City>
        <Name>The Rilton</Name>
        <Type>Budget</Type>
        <Price>150</Price>
    </hotel>
    <hotel>
        <City>London</City>
        <Name>The Rilton</Name>
        <Type>Standard</Type>
        <Price>250</Price>
    </hotel>
    <hotel>
        <City>London</City>
        <Name>The Lolipop</Name>
        <Type>Standard</Type>
        <Price>280</Price>
    </hotel>
    <hotel>
        <City>London</City>
        <Name>The non-Rilton</Name>
        <Type>Standard</Type>
        <Price>225</Price>
    </hotel>
    </hotels>
```

Comment: Also I am attempting to use Usort

function sortingsAt($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}


while saving all the prices into an array but sending them out is when i get into trouble.

Comment: Are you wanting to do the sorting in PHP? It's not clear from the title and the inclusion of javascript code in the question.

Comment: Yea, sorry i was trying to not be so ambiguous, and also trying to show how just incase javascript was needed, yea I'm trying to sort it in php before it gets "Echoed out"

Comment: Where are you getting the sort criterion from? Do you want to be able to sort on any aspect of the data?

Comment: Yea I'm trying to sort the "Price" to show from Lowest to highest, So the Lowest appearing at the top and the Highest at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a flexible function that you can use to sort by any criterion. I've also rewritten the XML parsing because you were doing it in a rather inefficient way.

I've used [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to extract the data from your XML document; it's a useful way of pulling out a set of nodes that match certain criteria without having to iterate through them.

The sort itself is done with [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), which allows you to define a callback for sorting your array items.

```
# this is the sort function; it takes two arguments, the aspect to sort on, and
# 'asc' or 'desc', depending on whether you want your sort ascending or descending
# the default is ascending

function sort_by( $aspect, $dir ){
    return function ($a, $b) use ($aspect, $dir) {
        if ($a[$aspect] == $b[$aspect]) {
            return 0;
        }
        if ($dir === 'asc') {
            return ($a[$aspect] > $b[$aspect]) ? +1 : -1;
        }
        else {
            return ($a[$aspect] > $b[$aspect]) ? -1 : +1;
        }
    };
}

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xmlFile);

# if you want to search for nodes in an XML document that meet certain criteria,
# there's a handy W3C standard for doing so; it's called XPath, and PHP has an
# interface for it in DOMXPath

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
# this is our "base" node
$hnode = $dom->getElementsByTagName("hotels")->item(0);

# get the data that we're searching for from $_GET:
# (you may want to do a little sanitising of these variables first...)
$city = $_GET['city'];
$type = $_GET['type'];

# set up the xpath query to search for hotels with City == $city and Type == $type
# our "base node" is <hotels>, and this query can be translated as "find all the
# direct children of <hotels> that have the tag <hotel> and the children of that
# <hotel> node include <City> with value $city and <Type> with value $type
$results = $xp->query('hotel[ City = $city and Type = $type ]', $hnode);

# check whether we have any results
if ($results->length === 0) {
    echo "<p>No hotels found.</p>\n";
}
else {
# we found hotels!!
    echo "<p>Found " . $results->length . " matching hotels</p>\n";

    # since we are doing the same operation on each XML node, we can condense the code
    # we create an associative array, $hotel, with the hotel properties and the values.
    # that then gets pushed on to an array, $h_data
    $attrs = array('City', 'Type', 'Name', 'Price');
    $h_data = array();
    foreach($results as $h)
    {   $hotel = array();
        foreach ($attrs as $a) {
            $hotel[$a] = $h->getElementsByTagName($a)->item(0)->nodeValue;
        }
        # push the associative array on to $h_data
        $h_data[] = $hotel;
    }

    # Here is the sort criteria. You could get/set this from the page -- e.g.
    # set up $_GET['sort_by'] and $_GET['sort_dir'] if you wanted
    $aspect = 'Price';
    $dir = 'desc'; # or 'desc' for descending

    # check that the aspect is valid -- it should be in the set of $attrs above
    if (! in_array($aspect, $attrs)) {
        $aspect = 'Price';
    }
    # set the search direction to 'asc' unless it is the recognised value 'desc'
    if ($dir !== 'asc' && $dir !== 'desc') {
        $dir = 'asc';
    }

    # pass it to the sorting function...
    usort($h_data, sort_by($aspect, $dir) );

    $html = '';
    # now create our output
    foreach ($h_data as $h) {
        $html .= "<p>" . $h['Name'] ."<br>". $h['Price'] ."<br>". $h['Type'] . "</p>\n";
    }
    echo $html;
}
```

Comment: His code above implies that you don't need to store (and subsequently sort) data unless $_GET["city"] === $city and $_GET["type"] === type; depending on the actual size of the XML document, this could have a pretty significant impact on the performance requirements for this code. Also, you might want to look into array_multisort(); it often out-performs usort() by a significant margin.

Comment: Re: the first point -- I missed that due to the lack of code indentation in the original! That implies that it might be better to do a query using DOMXPath to fetch the relevant nodes before parsing them. I'll update my code, anyway. Since you've already written an `array_multisort` version, there isn't much point in my doing so too, but the info about it outperforming `usort` is useful!

Comment: A DOMXPath is an interesting approach; and I wasn't suggesting you should rewrite the code to use `array_multisort`, just passing on a tip :)

Comment: I didn't think you were, don't worry. `:)` Thank you for the tip--it will go in my tip jar for future use!

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most efficient, because it loops over the list of hotels twice, but here's an [eval.in](https://eval.in/200288) that will sort things how you want. Note that I set the $_GET values at the top of the script - you'll likely not want to do that in your own code. ;)